# Running rails 7 tasks prompts debug console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems

While deploying a Rails 7 app in `Amazon Linux 2` machine i noticed that running:
`bundle exec rails db:migrate` or `bundle exec rails edit:credentials` but NOT with `bundle exec rails c -e production`, It just prompts the rdb console:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-86-136 current]$ bundle exec rake edit:credentials
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
/home/ec2-user/production/gw_outsourcing_backend/releases/7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/home/ec2-user/production/gw_outsourcing_backend/releases/7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:208: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/home/ec2-user/production/gw_outsourcing_backend/releases/7/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.1.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:504: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/aarch64-linux/continuation.so: warning: callcc is obsolete; use Fiber instead
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

/path/to/my/app/releases/7/config/application.rb:9:module RailsAppName
(rdb:1)
```

The `rails c -e production` won't run because i have to create my credentials first; but i can't create credentials or migrate the database because it prompts that console.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.7.0"
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.0"
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jwt'
# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
# gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'byebug'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mina'

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem "rack-cors"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end
```

How can I get the migration and credential edit commands to work, and why does that console prompts?

Answer (score -1):

By looking closely to the Gemfile i see `byebug` gem was not in the development group. I moved it to development group and tasks started working. The byebug gem does not work in production, and so it was failing but not explicitly outputting why.

Lesson learned, do not use byebug in production